# async_timeout.timeout vs asyncio.wait_for

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Previously I used `asyncio.wait_for` for timeout control and it worked pretty well. Recently, I learned aiohttp package and found that it used `asyncio_timeout.timeout` for timeout control instead. Then I read the github page (https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout) of asyncio_timeout. The author claimed that it runs faster than `asyncio.wait_for`. So I have two questions:

1. Can `asyncio_timeout.timeout` completely replace `asyncio.wait_for`? Should I replace all `asyncio.wait_for` to increase the speed? I'm writing a websocket client and `asyncio.wait_for` currently controls `websocket.recv` which is called frequently.
2. In the "Usage example" section (https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout), it seems that `asyncio_timeout.timeout` should be used with `async with`. But in the aiohttp help page, they use `with` instead of `async with` (http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). So which one is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `asyncio_timeout.timeout` is faster than `asyncio.wait_for`, true.
   `wait_for` creates a new task. It maybe doesn't matter for application code but very sufficient for libraries. For example `asyncpg` tried to use `wait_for` but rejected for sake of speed.
2. `asyncio_timeout` could be used everywhere except `tornado.web.RequestHandler.get` etc. Tornado still doesn't support tasks cancellation, I hope it will be fixed in tornado 5.0
3. Technically `async_timeout.timeout` works with both `async with` and just `with`. People were confused by `with` statement many times: in `asyncio` world async operations are encouraged. That's why I added asynchronous context manager support and encourage this usage. `with` will be supported for a long time for sake of backward compatibility anyway -- I just don't want to encourage this syntax.

**UPD** Python 3.11+ has native `async with asyncio.timeout():` support which is modelled after `async_timeout` but behaves more correctly in corner cases.